# Data fetch from url using urllib in python

Tags: python, request, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am trying to fetch the data from url like : "http://www.sears.com/search=refrigerators"

This is what I tried:

```
>>> from cookielib import CookieJar
>>> import urllib
>>> import urllib2
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = {}
>>> data['search'] = 'refrigerators'
>>> url_values = urllib.urlencode(data)
>>> cj = CookieJar()
>>> opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
>>> url = 'http://www.sears.com'
>>> full_url = url + '/' + url_values
>>> f = opener.open(full_url).read()
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "html.parser")
>>> print(soup.title)
<title>Shopping Tourism: Shop Internationally at Sears</title>
>>> f = opener.open(full_url).read()
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "html.parser")
>>> print(soup.title)
<title>Refrigerators from Sears.com</title>
```

I am getting different title instead of getting same :(. (May be I am getting title for the home page first)

Why is happening?
Please help me to get the search page data.

Comment: If i click on the link you posted, the title in the tab is "Refrigerators from Sears.com"

Comment: What is the exact issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using requests Session object, which is their version of a CookieJar, but this gets the title of `Refrigerators from Sears.com`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()

r = s.get("http://www.sears.com/search=refrigerators")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

print soup.title
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @heinst. Actually i want the title "Refrigerators from Sears.com" itself. But if you save your code as a python file and execute, It will give "Shopping Tourism: Shop Internationally at Sears" as the title. That is the issue dude.

Comment: @rash are you not located in the US? It sounds like you're trying to connect to the website from outside the US by the title you're getting

Comment: I am from India. I am using python 2.7.9 . Thanks a lot for your effort dude.